# Formula to find the column number of last non-zero number in a row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find the column number of the last non-zero cell in a range. I have tried the following formulas:

=MAX((O8:BA8<>0)*(COLUMN(O8:BA8)))

=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((O8:BA8<>0)*COLUMN(O8:BA8)))

But for both of these, although my range is only 39 values wide... (from column O to BA), it keeps giving me a return value of 45, which cannot be the answer since it has to be less than 39, and the answer actually is 31.

The below snapshot is a sample of the rows that I need to do this for. It is  a mix of 0s and numbers greater than 0 (hours logged). Each row begins and stops the hours logged on different dates, so this is why I am trying to get the column number - so I can use this to look up the corresponding dates for the last hours logged by row. If you have any other suggestions for this end goal, I would greatly appreciate it also. Otherwise, I would love to know if anybody has a way to get the **correct** column number!

[image: Link to screenshot since it wont let me post it yet]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Though your range may be 39 columns wide, the column range starts at `O`. Therefor your Boolean conversion to numbers when you multiply with the column of your range can range from to 15 to 53 if my calculations are correct.

Comment: If you have formulas in columns beyond the last value, that may also generate a "false last column" and not what you're looking for.

Comment: You are getting the absolute column number, but you need the relative one. You could add the following string `-COLUMN(O8)+1` to your formulas to account for this. Another way I found is `=LOOKUP(2,1/(O8:BA8<>0),COLUMN(O8:BA8))-COLUMN(O8)+1`. Hopefully, a better compact solution will come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite evident from your description that your title is misleading, i.e. you are not in fact looking to return the "column number", but rather the *relative position* within the range O8:BA8, which can be achieved simply via:

`=MATCH(1,0/O8:BA8)`

Note that this will error if all entries in the range are zero.

Comment: this formula worked, thank you! I apologize for being misleading, Im not too familiar with describing what I need to do within excel. Appreciate this!